# While the firmware's set to UEFI and Secure Boot is ON, booting from bootable ubuntu usb pen drive that is not GPT partitioned - WORKED. How?

Tags: boot, 18.04, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Over my system, the firmware setting are **not** set to legacy but they are set to **UEFI with secure boot on.**

Then, I could boot from a bootable ubuntu usb pen drive that is not GPT partitioned successfully.
I am wondering how this could happen as UEFI requires the bootable medium to be of GPT partitioned. Right? **So how did this work?**

In below image **disk 2** is the USB Pen drive I am referring too. You can see it's not GPT partitioned. The pen drive is of 8Gig capacity. And it has Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 bootable version in it.
But surprisingly the free size show by windows as 7720 MB is definitely wrong. Any comments on this?
[image: disk 2 is pen drive]

**The USB Drive Contents -**
[image: USB Drive Contents]

**The contents in boot folder.**
[image: boot folder]

**The contents in System Volume Information folder**
[image: System Volume Information folder]

Comment: No, UEFI does not require GPT partitioned disks to boot.  Windows requires GPT when run in UEFI mode, Ubuntu does not care.  Usual practice is to use GPT for UEFI, but without Windows, it is just to avoid the four primary partition limit.

Comment: 1) does windows do this ( i.e. when in UEFI boot mode windows boots from only GPT disk and not MBR disk) for any reason?

Comment: 2) If i got it right,  when in legacy mode - nothing (windows/ubuntu/other OS's etc) can boot  from GPT. Obvious, I suppose?

Comment: Who can say why Windows does this.  Legacy mode on a gpt disk boots just fine, if you give it a place to store the bootloader which can no longer be slipped between the partitions.  A small 2M partition (unformatted) with the bios-grub flag is required to identify this location.